# An exception just caused my code to stop debug, and showing on a simple statement

Tags: c++, exception, c++17

Please, can anyone tell me whats wrong in this code. 
I have no idea about these kind of exceptions.
Compiler is just showing this - 
Exception thrown: read access violation. **a** was 0x1D54112. occurred
Is this due to an if statement is inside a loop, which is also inside another loop ??
Here is the code -

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter the number of walkers - ";
    cin >> n;
    int* a = new int[n];
    cout << endl << "Enter the distances of walkers from Rick : ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
        {
            if (a[j] > a[j + 1])
            {
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j + 1];
                a[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << endl << "The distance of walkers from Rick are - ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    int c = 0, i = 0, k = 0;
    while (c == 0 || i < n)
    {
        a[i] = 0;         //exception is being shown here.
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
        {
            a[j] -= 1;    //and here too!!.
            if (j % 6 == 0) a[j]--;
            if (a[j] == 0)
            {
                c = 1;
                k = j;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (c == 0) cout << endl << "Rick now go and save Carl and Judas" << endl;
    else if (c == 1)
    {
        cout << endl << "Goodbye Rick" << endl;
        cout << "He was able to kill " << k << " walkers. " << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: 'Is it due to ...', no it's due to bugs in your code.

Comment: `while (c == 0 || i < n)` I think you want `&&` there.

Comment: Undoubtedly the bugs are due to `i` and/or `j` being too big for the array `a` on the lines you  indicated. And that will be due to logic errors in your code. I'm not following the logic, so I'm not sure what to suggest as fixes.

Comment: not related (maybe): use meaningful names for variables. `i` and `j` are ok (they are used by everyone as indexer or counter), c and k stands for? `a` should be something as `distances` . `int c` can result only in 0 or 1: sound it should be replaced with a `bool   rickGoodbye = false`